# Двойная сортировка по массиву

Tags: php

Добрый день профессионалы, нужно было отсортировать массив по возрасту. Мне дали хороший совет реализации в php7 (см ниже). Но как мне добавить дополнительную сортировку по Имени, после того как отсортировалось по возрасту?  (в реальном примере людей больше 500 а возраст указан только у 10%)

```
<?php
    $entries=array();
    $entries[0]["displayname"]="Ivan"  ;
    $entries[0]["age"]=32              ;
    $entries[1]["displayname"]="Anna"  ;
    $entries[1]["age"]=24              ;
    $entries[2]["displayname"]="Bob"   ;
    $entries[2]["age"]=29              ;
    $entries[3]["displayname"]="Stuart";
    $entries[3]["age"]=28              ;

    For ($i=0; $i<4; $i++) {echo $entries[$i]["displayname"] .' '. $entries[$i]["age"].'<br>';}
    ?>
```

Решение:

```
usort($entries,function($a,$b) { 
    return $a['age'] > $b['age'];
});
```

Comment: возможно стоит взглянуть в сторону [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-multisort.php)

Comment: Этот массив у вас точно не из БД берется? А то сортировку в запросе стоило бы сделать сразу.

Comment: не, не из БД. смотрю сейчас array multisort, хорошая штука...

Comment: если успею сам до того как мне тут ответ дадут то тоже хорошо :)

Comment: YES получилось, через мультисорт... :) спасибо..

Answer (score 0):

```
usort($entries, function($a, $b) {
    if (!is_numeric($a['age']) && is_numeric($b['age'])) {
        // Не указан возраст А
        return false;
    } else if (is_numeric($a['age']) && !is_numeric($b['age'])) {
        // Не указан возраст Б
        return true;
    } else
    if (is_numeric($a['age']) && is_numeric($b['age']) && ($a['age'] != $b['age'])) {
        // Сравниваем по возрасту
        return $a['age'] > $b['age'];
    } else {
        // Если оба возраста не указаны, или указаны и равны, то сравниваем по имени
        return $a['displayname'] > $b['displayname'];
    }
});
```

Comment: Да нет, тут всё проще. зачем проверять является ли числом элемент массива. Наверное я неправильно объяснил. Нужно, что бы просто шла сортировка сперва по возрасту, а потом по имени. там где возраста нет - автоматически уходит на второй план и сортируется после возраста. Например: Юля 22, Анастасия 23, Семен 24, Андрей, Баходыр, Иван, Юлдаш. Вот так :) И всё это один массив. А multi-array, пиииип, не сортирует числа.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю почему заработала сортировка array_multisort, хотя все на забугорных сайтах ругают что она не сортирует числа. Короче вот простая реализация моего вопроса. Возраст - это extansionattribute2

```
foreach ($entries as $key => $row) {
     $extensionattribute2[$key]  = $row['extensionattribute2'];
     $displayname[$key]  = $row['displayname'];
    array_multisort($extensionattribute2, SORT_DESC, $displayname, SORT_ASC, $entries);
```

Comment: Как только в списке появятся 7-летние дети, вы сразу поймёте, о чём говорили эти буржуи :)